# How to calculate the time a function elapses

Tags: visual-c++, timer

all, I need to compute how much time a function elapses for a range of numbers of data, e.g. 100, 200, 300, 400. This is my code:

```
// start timer
time (&start);

someFun(some parameters);

// end timer
time (&end);
dif = difftime(end,start);

cstrTime.Format( _T("It took you %.6lf seconds to finish prediction.\n"),dif);
AfxMessageBox(cstrTime);
```

now, the problem is no matter how large the size for the input of 'someFun' is, it always returns me 1.000000 sec. So I am wondering maybe I should go for a more precise timer? any idea guys?

cheers

Comment: When in doubt, always consult the documentation first. (This is the polite form of "RTFM".)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`difftime` has a resolution of seconds](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ctime/difftime/), as you can see in your results.

You should implement a [Win32 High Resolution Timer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/nl-nl/library/windows/desktop/ms644900%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#high_resolution) for this. [Samples here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/nl-nl/library/windows/desktop/ms644904%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).